# Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException--

Tags: java, javafx

### i am working in javafx project and i face this problem when press show button to show image from the ressource:
...................................................................................................................................................................................................
[image]

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1862)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1729)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:459)
at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1385)
at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$12(ContextMenuContent.java:1338)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
```

```
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3856)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1851)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2584)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:412)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

this is my main programe:

```java
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

this my controler

```java
package sample;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Controller {
    public TextArea txt1;
    public TextArea txt2;
    public TextArea txt3;
    public Stage primaryStage;

    public void close() {
        Platform.exit();
    }
//////****************to save input from user and write it to txt format file*************************//////////
    public void save() {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

        //Set extension filter
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter =
                new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("TXT files (*.txt)", "*.txt");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);
        //Show save file dialog
        File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);

        if (file != null) {
            saveTextToFile(txt1.getText(), file);
        }
    }

    private void saveTextToFile(String text, File file) {
        try {
            PrintWriter writer;
            writer = new PrintWriter(file);
            writer.println(text);
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        }
 ///////***********************to read txt file and print their content into text area 1***********///////

    public void open() {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setTitle("Open Resource File");
        File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (file != null) {
            txt1.setText(readFile(file));

        }
    }

    private String readFile(File file) {
        StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

        try {

            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            String text;
            while ((text = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(text);
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                assert bufferedReader != null;
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }

    public void afficher() throws FileNotFoundException {
        //Creating an image
        Image image = null;
        try (FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("resource/photo_2021-02-12_18-06-09.jpg")) {
            image = new Image(stream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ImageView imageview = new ImageView(image);

        StackPane layout = new StackPane(imageview);
        layout.getChildren().addAll(imageview);
        Scene scene1= new Scene(layout, 400, 100);
        // New window (Stage)
        Stage stage= new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("automata diagram");
        stage.setScene(scene1);
        stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        // Specifies the owner Window (parent) for new window
        stage.initOwner(stage);
        // Set position of second window, related to primary window.
        stage.setX(stage.getX() + 200);
        stage.setY(stage.getY() + 100);
        stage.show();

    }


}
```

my fxml file :

```xml
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.2" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
  <MenuBar layoutY="-1.0" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="600.0">
    <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
      <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#open" text="Open File " />
      <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#save" text="save as" />
      <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#close" text="Close" />
    </Menu>
    <Menu mnemonicParsing="false"  text="show">
         <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#afficher" text="show diagram" />
         </items></Menu>
    <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
      <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About My project" />
    </Menu>
  </MenuBar>
  <TextArea fx:id="txt1" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="40.0" prefHeight="250.0" prefWidth="162.0" wrapText="true">
      <cursor>
         <Cursor fx:constant="DEFAULT" />
      </cursor></TextArea>
  <TextArea fx:id="txt2" editable="false" layoutX="225.0" layoutY="40.0" prefHeight="250.0" prefWidth="162.0">
    <cursor>
      <Cursor fx:constant="E_RESIZE" />
    </cursor>
  </TextArea>
  <TextArea fx:id="txt3" editable="false" layoutX="424.0" layoutY="40.0" prefHeight="250.0" prefWidth="162.0" />
  <Button layoutX="102.0" layoutY="329.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="148.0" text="Analyse" textFill="#e40404" />
  <Button layoutX="335.0" layoutY="329.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="148.0" text="Separation" textFill="#e40404" />
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: We need to see the entire stack trace of your exception.  The `Caused by:` section is the most important part—it shows the actual cause of your problem.

Comment: [mcve] please .. which must contain the complete stacktrace (as @VGR already suggested), must be stripped down to contain _only_ the parts that are related to the problem (no need for unrelated ui).